# WebStorm TypeScript less auto-completion suggestion

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, typescript, webstorm

Using WebStorm with TypeScript a lot, I would like to know if it's possible to limit some autocompletion suggestions.

Basically, how to avoid this, to have only one suggestion per function.
[image]

Comment: What bothers me from your screenshot .. is the fact that you have *the same signature twice*. For me this suggests that you have somehow included/referenced the same file twice. I suggest looking into that -- at least you will see less entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to avoid this,

Sadly you can't. WebStorm tries to be as aggressive as possible and therefore can give false positives.